# Solidity percentage calculation with variables vs literals gives different answers

Tags: solidity

```
contract test {
    function calculatePrice(uint a, uint b) public pure  returns (uint) {
        return (a * (b / 100));
    }

    function calculatePrice2() public pure  returns (uint) {
        return (80 * (60 / 100));
    }
}
```

So, the above two functions even though completely same give different answers.
for the first function if you pass a=80 and b=60 answer is zero but if you call the second function the answer is 48.

Why? the code is exactly the same except the first function is dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function calculates with unsigned integers, meaning there are no decimals.

It first calculates 60 / 100, which results in 0 (integer, no decimals). And then calculates 80 * 0, which is still 0.

---

The second function takes the intermediate result as the [fixed point number](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#fixed-point-numbers) type.

It first calculates 60 / 100, resulting in 0.6 (fixed point number, not integer). And then calculates 80 * 0.6, resulting in 48.

Comment: `function calculatePrice3(uint a, uint b) public pure  returns (uint) { return a * b / 100; }`

will also return 48, so how does the omittance of brackets affect the answer?

Comment: @Sam When there's no parentheses present, it calculates from left to right (but still giving precedence to `*` and `/` over `+` and `-`). So in this case, the function first calculates 80 * 60, which is 4800. And then divides by 100, resulting in 48.